# show segue(programmatically) when selecting place from GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController

Tags: swift, segue, uisearchbar, google-places, gmsautocomplete

I am having some issues with segueing to a new viewcontroller via the show segue. I have been able to use the present segue, but want to use a push/show navigation stack. I am getting this error... "an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated." Thanks for any help in advance!

// segue to searchVC from homecontroller

```
    func handleSearch() {
        let vc = SearchVC()
        show(vc, sender: self)

    }
```

// setup search bar in searchVC class

```
    func loadPlacesSearchBar() {

        searchController?.searchBar.isHidden = false

        resultsViewController = GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController()
        resultsViewController?.delegate = self

        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsViewController)
        searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = resultsViewController

        // Put the search bar in the navigation bar.
        searchController?.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        navigationItem.titleView = searchController?.searchBar
        searchController?.searchBar.placeholder = "search places"

        // When UISearchController presents the results view, present it in
        // this view controller, not one further up the chain.
        definesPresentationContext = true

        // Prevent the navigation bar from being hidden when searching.
        searchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

    }
```

// extension from SearchVC

```
extension SearchVC: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewControllerDelegate {

    func resultsController(_ resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController,
                           didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {

        searchController?.isActive = false

        // Do something with the selected place.

        let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
        autocompleteController.delegate = self as? GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate

        print("Place name: \(place.name)")
        print("Place address: \(String(describing: place.formattedAddress))")
        print("Place attributions: \(String(describing: place.attributions))")

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        let mapView = MapViewController()
        show(mapView, sender: self)

//        let mapView = MapViewController()
//        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mapView)
//        present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }

    func resultsController(_ resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController,
                           didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error){
        // TODO: handle the error.
        print("Error: ", error.localizedDescription)
    }

    // Turn the network activity indicator on and off again.
    func didRequestAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    }

    func didUpdateAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're running into this is that the `searchController` will be dismissed when you make your selection, and thus, be in the middle of an animation when you're trying to push that new view controller.

A very simple solution that works for me is setting your view controller as a `UISearchControllerDelegate`, and then calling your segue after the `searchController` has been dismissed.

```
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsViewController)
    searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = resultsViewController
    searchController?.delegate = self //<- add this
```

Then conform to the Delegate and implement this

```
extension YourViewController:UISearchControllerDelegate {

func didDismissSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
   // perform your segue, or push/present your view controller here
}
```